# POST запрос, программная авторизация C#

Tags: c#

Не могу программно войти на сайт https://www.marathonbet.com:443/su/. Мне более-менее ясно, когда есть что-то типа login.php?username=...&password=... А тут htm страница.

Вот что Chrome говорит про эту форму: 
Если у нее поле action передает данные на login.htm, то как мне формировать запрос?

Логин:

```
<input type="text" name="username" id="loginpage_form_username" size="20" regex="^[0-9]{6,7}|[A-Za-z0-9\-_\.\%\+]+@([A-Za-z0-9\-_]+\.)+[A-Za-z]{2,4}$" class="required error" aria-required="true">
```

Пароль:

```
<input type="password" name="password" id="loginpage_form_password" size="20" regex="^.{6,}$" class="required" aria-required="true">
```

Comment: скорее всего там стоит аутентификация через сертификат, о чем и сообщает гугл "необходим сертификат клиентской аутентификации", для такой аутентификации не бывает полей логина и пароля, он устанавливается в систему

Comment: И еще один момент, "Доступ к запрашиваемому вами интернет-ресурсу ограничен в соответствии с требованиями Законодательства Российской Федерации."

Comment: так, и че делать теперь? программно зайти невозможно что ли? я с HTTP-запросами толком не разбирался еще, пару раз только нужны были, но там все просто получалось.. через .php?login= и тд.

Comment: рыть в сторону аутентификации с помощью сертификата, для этого сертификат должен быть установлен в приложении если я не ошибаюсь

Comment: а если пойти напролом - и просто загрузить страницу в WinForm'овский бразуер и перебирать все input'ы циклом foreach? или так тоже не прокатит?

Comment: там нет инпутов, я же уже написал, аутентификация через сертификат

Comment: а вот это тогда что? <input type="text" name="username" id="loginpage_form_username" size="20" regex="^[0-9]{6,7}|[A-Za-z0-9\-_\.\%\+]+@([A-Za-z0-9\-_]+\.)+[A-Za-z]{2,4}$" class="required error" aria-required="true">

Comment: я не могу увидеть страницу, в российском сегменте интернет она заблокирована

Comment: про сертификаты можете прочитать  тут https://www.cryptopro.ru/forum2/default.aspx?g=posts&t=5851

Comment: во я Chrome попросил показать мне, что за текст бокс такой, где надо логин вводить. вот он мне показал: <input type="text" name="username" id="loginpage_form_username" size="20" regex="^[0-9]{6,7}|[A-Za-z0-9\-_\.\%\+]+@([A-Za-z0-9\-_]+\.)+[A-Za-z]{2,4}$" class="required error" aria-required="true">. что если просто загрузить страницу программно и переберать ее циклом?

Comment: тогда смотрите какой экшен на форме и туда отправляйте запрос

Comment: @Dmitry: `в российском сегменте интернет она заблокирована` У меня норм. Сейчас сижу не через VPN.

Comment: @Dmitry, вот я же и спрашиваю. акшин вот какой <form id="login_form" action="https://www.marathonbet.com:443/su/login.htm". как запрос-то сформировать?

Comment: @romeo, мне yota его блокирует

Comment: @Кто-то: А в чём собственно проблема? Какая разница между `login.htm` и `login.php`? В современных веб-приложениях запрос проходит через [роутинг](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/routing), потому не важно какое расширение или есть ли оно, главное URL должен быть валидным. То что в форме вы увидели незнакомые для себя атрибуты, к примеру, regex, то это всё для валидации формы на клиенте, причём сделанной javascript-ом, т.е. вас как "парсера" не должно это волновать. В той форме поле с паролем имеет имя `login_password`, а не `password`.

Comment: @Кто-то: Потому ваш запрос должен выглядеть `https://www.marathonbet.com:443/su/login.htm?login=foo&login_password=pass`. Логин должен состоять либо из цифр в количестве 6-7 штук, либо это должен быть email. Пароль: любые символы, но в количестве от 6 и выше. Если не сработает, то попробуйте сделать запрос на незащищённую версию `http://www.marathonbet.com:80/su/login.htm?login=foo&login_password=pass`. CSRF защиты я не вижу. Также у ресурса имеется [другая форма авторизации](https://www.marathonbet.com/su/loginpage.htm), но уже с каптчей.

Comment: @romeo Пожалуйста, опубликуйте ваши комментарии в виде ответа.